# postgresql way to insert row with "ON CONFLICT" clause semantics

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert-update, upsert

Is there an easy way in postgres to do the equivalent of the following in sqlite?

```
INSERT INTO foo (x, y, z) VALUES (1, 2, 3) ON CONFLICT replace;
```

I've looked around and the solutions I've found are complicated custom functions. The other solution to my problem is to just do

```
delete from foo where x=1; INSERT INTO foo (x, y, z) VALUES (1, 2, 3) ON CONFLICT replace;
```

which isn't semantically equivalent but works for my case.

I'd just prefer the `ON CONFLICT` rule if it doesn't require a custom function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert, on duplicate update (postgresql)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql)

Comment: Long story short, no.  There is no simple syntax for this in postgres.

Comment: I read that question. His case wants to do an insert or update. I need an insert or replace.

Comment: The answer is the same.  There is no simple syntax for this in postgres, and you'll have to use a procedure/multiple queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of PostgreSQL version 9.1 (beta at this moment), you can use a [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) to do an insert-or-replace:

```
/**
CREATE TABLE foo(id serial primary key, content text unique);
**/

WITH replace AS (
    DELETE FROM foo
    WHERE
        content = 'bar'
    RETURNING content
)
INSERT INTO 
    foo(content) -- values:
SELECT
    *
FROM replace RIGHT JOIN (SELECT CAST('bar' AS text) as content) sub USING(content);
```

'bar' is the value that will be inserted or replaced.

It's not working in older versions, you have to wait :-(

Comment: Note that this is *not* safe in the presence of concurrency unless you take a table-level lock.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 9.5, PostgreSQL provides "UPSERT" functionality.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html

Notice the ON CONFLICT part in command Synopsis